# Why are my codes of Code Snippets not working?

Tags: code-snippets, bbpress

I have recently downloaded bbpress but when users log in on the front end they can access the admin area and have the bar across the top which contains a link to remove it. I know nothing about code at all, I've only been blogging a few weeks so after doing a bit of reading I decided to download the plugin Code Snippets and add the following codes.

```
function annointed_admin_bar_remove() {
        global $wp_admin_bar;

        /* Remove their stuff */
        $wp_admin_bar->remove_menu('wp-logo');
}

add_action('wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'annointed_admin_bar_remove', 0);
```

and

```
// disable access to wp-admin for non-administrators
function block_wp_admin_access() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) && ! ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'block_wp_admin_access' );
```

Neither of these has worked and since I don't know anything about code, I don't know why they aren't working. I can't seem to find a plugin that does this for you either.

Comment: You need to test it in another browser or computer and see if the user are really seeing the admin bar. You are logged in to backend already so when you go to the front page, it will show you the admin bar for quick edits but non-admin users should not see it, to test that, use another browser where you are not logged in.

Comment: Already tried that and it still happened. I am now using the plug in WPS Hide Login which is working. :)